# What's the most appropriate English translation for 'Bildsprache'?

Tags: translation

I've seen 'visual language' offered as a translation but I've never encountered this in English before. Would 'visual identity' be more fitting?

Context: It's relating to an advertising\marketing campaign.

Comment: I think that's a question for https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not the right forum here, but: *imagery* may fit in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the English term most widely used for this is ['figurative language'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_and_figurative_language).

> **Figurative** (or **non-literal**) language uses words in a way that deviates from their conventionally accepted definitions in order to convey a more complicated meaning or heightened effect. Figurative language is often created by presenting words in such a way that they are equated, compared, or associated with normally unrelated meanings.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figurative) gives the following definition for *figurative*:

> 2 a : expressing one thing in terms normally denoting another with which it may be regarded as analogous : [METAPHORICAL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphorical)
>   //  *figurative* language